# Updates to global variables from different nodes in a scripted Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, global

How are updates to global variables synchronized in a Jenkins scripted pipeline?

Here is a simplified code where the global variable in 'mylist'

```
def mylist = []                             // Global Variable
def jobs = [:]
def joblist = [“A”, “B”]
joblist.each {it->
    jobs[it] = {
        node() {
            stage(it) {
                // lots of processing ...
                mylist.add(it)            // Global variable update in jobs running in parallel
            }
        }
    } 
}
parallel jobs
```

I want it to contain either [A,B] or [B,A] if the jobs ran successfully.

Questions:

1. Is this guaranteed or could there be concurrency issues?
2. Is the update in the master immediate or does it take place after the job completes?
3. What if mylist is a complex data structure where different jobs update different parts of the data structure?

Comment: @zett42 - thanks for that helpful link. Does it imply that to update a global data structure, I should create a "global" function to update the data structure? Does this also mean that a remote call is made from the agent to the master for that function?

Comment: The only thing you need to change is `def mylist = [].asSynchronized()`. This makes it so that calls to `mylist.add()` will be synchronized between threads. You don't need a global function. Also there will be no remote call from the agent to the master, because pipeline Groovy code always runs on the master, regardless of `node()`, see [this old documentation](https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-plugin/blob/master/TUTORIAL.md): "_Every Pipeline build itself runs on the master, using a flyweight executor — an uncounted slot that is assumed to not take any significant computational power._"

Comment: Thank you! That explains a lot and will help me adjust my thinking about 180 degrees :).